# poner dos o mas botones dentro de un Form y que no lo activen

Tags: php, html, sql

bueno tengo un nuevo problema que no logro resolver y es que trato de tener un form con un botón dentro que va ir incrementando el numero de ventas pero al ser un botón hace lo que el form pide que es una action pero no quiero mandar lo aun sino que tener otro botón que este si envié la información, adjunto código:

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="monitoreo_x_region.php">
    <input type='button' name="ventas" id="aumentar" value="0" onclick="aumentar()">
    <script>
          var inicio = 0; //se inicializa una variable en 0
            function aumentar(){ // se crean la funcion y se agrega al evento onclick en en la etiqueta button con id aumentar
            var cantidad = document.getElementById("aumentar").value = ++inicio; //se obtiene el valor del input, y se incrementa en 1 el valor que tenga.
            }
    </script>
    <button type="submit" id="botonop" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Agregar ventas</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí esta la solución anmigo, y procurar cuando vaya a trabajar con el DOM, cargar siempre el script al final o entrar el codigo dentro de este evento para cargar una vez la pagina haya cargado el documento HTML,

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" ()=>{  
//Colocar aqui todo el codigo que quiera ejecuptar una vez la pagina cargue. 
document.getElementById("botonop").addEventListener('click', (event)=>{  
event.preventDefault();  
});  
var inicio = 0;  
function aumentara(){  
var cantidad = document.getElementById("aumentar").value = ++inicio;  
});
```

```html
    <form method="post" role="form" action="monitoreo_x_region.php">
    <input type='button' name="ventas" id="aumentar" value="0" onclick="aumentara()">
    <button type="submit" id="botonop" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Agregar ventas</button>
</form>
    <script>
           document.getElementById("botonop").addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            });
          var inicio = 0; //se inicializa una variable en 0
            function aumentara(){ // se crean la funcion y se agrega al evento onclick en en la etiqueta button con id aumentar
            var cantidad = document.getElementById("aumentar").value = ++inicio;
            //se obtiene el valor del input, y se incrementa en 1 el valor que tenga.
            }
    </script>
```